# Real Analysis Zero Set

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the interval [0,1] is not a zero set.

Suppose [0,1] is a zero set. I'm stuck here. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: To start, look up the definition of "zero set".

Comment: Is measure theory??

Comment: @vadim123 I know what a zero set is,  Reduce to a finite subcover. Get a sequence of intervals (ak,bk) so that  ak+1<bk covering [0,1]. This is what I have for this problem, but once I have a covering, how do I use the triangle inequality to produce a contradiction?

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran No this Introduction to Real Analysis, we aren't in a measure theory course.

Comment: You should put your efforts in the question, with more detail.

Comment: Is this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeroSet.html ?

Comment: @vadim123 thanks, what I have so far are just ideas.

Comment: @AsdrubalBeltran Our definition is, A set D contained in R is a zero set if for each epsilon > 0 there is a countable covering of D by open intervals (ai, bi) such that the sum i=0 to infinity (bi - ai) <= epsilon.

Comment: That is not what zero set usually means. You should have included the definition in the first place.

Comment: @KevinCarlson No, not a zero set of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce to a finite subcover by $n$ elements. Since the sum of all lengths is less than $\epsilon,$ each length is less than $\epsilon/n$. Suppose $\epsilon=1/2$. We can order the intervals by their left endpoints. Then the first interval, i.e. the one covering $0$, extends no further than $1/2n$. Thus the second interval extends no further than $1/n$-otherwise its left endpoint would have to be above $1/2n$ and $1/2n$ would be missed. Continuing in this way, a connected union $n$ intervals of length no more than $1/2n$, containing $0$, can't extend beyond $1/2$. But one of them is supposed to contain $1$-contradiction.

Comment: nice, I can see where this is going. Thanks for sharing your idea.